# Angular.js listener for new DOM elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have a library which creates custom input fields for radiobuttons and checkboxes.
The library is cloning DOM elements. After cloning them, Angular stuff like models are not working anymore.
Here is a little example of the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/7oxq8vka/1/
How can I tell Angular to listen for DOM changes and update its listeners? Like `myApp.updateDom();`
Or if that is not possible, how can I add these listeners outside of the Angular code? Is it possible to do something like `myApp.addListener($(this));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('my', function($scope){
    $('.custom').each(function() {
        var clone = $(this).clone().removeClass('custom');        
        $(this).after(clone).remove();        
    });        
 });
```

Here : http://jsfiddle.net/7oxq8vka/6/

Comment: Okay, thanks. So it's only possible to do it within the library? There is no was to tell Angular to watch DOM changes and then apply them?

Comment: Hm, I noticed that you fiddle just works because the JS fails and the cloning does not affect. How do I get the `$rootScope`?

Comment: Oops didn't see that. You actually should be creating an Angular Directive for whatever DOM manipulation you want to do. Try the updated one, not a good solution though.

Comment: That means I'm not able to use other external libraries which make DOM manipulation with Angular?

Comment: Isn't the new fiddle working? You can use other libraries which do DOM manipulation with AngularJS, but it is a good practice to wrap those libraries into Angular directives, you can google for how that can be done.

Comment: It's working, but I was hoping it is possible without wrapping it into Angular.